# project how to redesign to use unique dao

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, refactoring

I have two projects, but they are not using the same DAO layer, and one project use an URL request to invoke the methods from the other project.
I encountered a problem, when I create an entity, I have to create separated DAO, service and so on. This DAO is use different fragement.

I want to find one method or a sweet design pattern to use the unique abstract DAO, and change the URL invoke way to a clearer and more changeable way.

My code is like:

```
public static String apiDeviceEdit(Device device, HttpSession session,
            Long operate) {
        String userId = (String) session
                .getAttribute(CommonAttributes.API_USERID_SESSION);
        String token = (String) session
                .getAttribute(CommonAttributes.API_TOKEN_SESSION);
        Assert.notNull(userId);
        Assert.notNull(token);
        String param = "user_id=" + userId + "&device_sn=" + device.getfSn()
                + "&operate=" + operate + "&token=" + token;

        String string = sendPost(setting.getApiDeviceEdit(), param,
                "DeviceEdit");

        return string;

    }
```

the different Dao like that:

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class ConductorDao extends BaseHBDao <Conductor, Long> {

    @Autowired
    public ConductorDao (@Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory session) {

        super ();
        this.setSessionFactory (session);
    }
}

public interface ConductorDao extends BaseDao<Conductor, Long> {

     final String SELECT_BY_SN = "from Conductor c where c.sn =:sn";
    Conductor findBySn(String sn) throws Exception;
    Page<Conductor> findByUserId(Long getfId, Pageable pageable);

}

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class ConductorDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<Conductor, Long> implements ConductorDao {

    @Override
    public Conductor findBySn(String sn) throws Exception {
        List<Conductor> conductors = entityManager.createQuery(SELECT_BY_SN).setParameter("sn", sn).getResultList();
        if (conductors == null || conductors.size()== 0) {
            return new Conductor();
        }
        else {
            return conductors.get(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Conductor> findByUserId(Long getfId, Pageable pageable) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Conductor> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Conductor.class);
        Root<Conductor> root = criteriaQuery.from(Conductor.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(root);
        Predicate restrictions = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
        restrictions = criteriaBuilder.and(restrictions, criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("userId"), getfId));
        criteriaQuery.where(restrictions);
        return super.findPage(criteriaQuery, pageable);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok add third layer of abstraction, call it business and make all your call to the dao layer from this new project, cut all the call that goes directly to the dao to use your business tier. then you can use your two jars of the dao in that project, and by doing so you can expose it as rest, or web services if you want.